# How to make Multi select without using bootstrap and with only pure css?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Now, I am making a multi-select component that has a heading inside the select box.
I made the  tag inside the div component and every item is  tag.
This is my code.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import "./style.css";

function Select({ title, data, changeSelect, selectedItem }) {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState(data);
  const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState([]);

  const wrapperRef = useRef(null);
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  const handleClickOutside = event => {
    if (wrapperRef.current && !wrapperRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
      setIsVisible(false);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("click", handleClickOutside, false);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", handleClickOutside, false);
    };
  }, []);

  

  const selectItem = (item) => {
    if (selectedItems.indexOf(item) === -1) {
      if (categories.length === 1) {
      }
      setCategories((prevCategories) =>
        prevCategories.filter((value) => value !== item)
      );
      setSelectedItems((prevItems) => [...prevItems, item]);
    }
  };

  const removeItem = (item) => {
    setSelectedItems((items) => items.filter((value) => value !== item));
    setCategories((prevCategories) => [...prevCategories, item]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="custom-select" ref={wrapperRef} >
      {/* <label className="append-label">{title}</label> */}
      <div className="multi-select" >
        <title>{title}</title>
        <div className="multi-select-wrapper">
          {selectedItems.length > 0 &&
            selectedItems.map((item) => (
              <span onClick={() => removeItem(item)}>{item}</span>
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={`dropDown-wrapper ${isVisible ? "active" : ""}`}>
        <ul>
          {categories.length > 0 &&
            categories.map((item) => (
              <li onClick={() => selectItem(item)}>{item}</li>
            ))}
          <li
            style={{
              display: `${categories.length === 0 ? "block" : "none"}`,
            }}
          >
            No Result
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Select;
```

When I click the select button, it shows a dropdown box.
The most important thing here is that I used react-onclickoutside npm library to get the click event outside the current element but it is not working well.
I used several libraries but all of them do not work at all.

PS: I have to use 3 multi-selects.

- react: 16.14.0
- react-scripts: 3.4.3
- react-onclickoutside: 6.10.0

Answer (score 0):

I had a solution by using another npm library and stopPropagation() function.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import ClickOutside from "react-click-outside";
import "./style.css";

function Select({ title, data, changeSelect, selectedItem }) {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState(data);
  const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState([]);

  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  // const onClickSelect = (e, active) => {
  //   setIsActive(active);
  //   console.log(e.target.value, "asdfasdfasdfs");
  // };

  const selectItem = (item) => {
    if (selectedItems.indexOf(item) === -1) {
      if (categories.length === 1) {
        setIsActive(false);
      }
      setCategories((prevCategories) =>
        prevCategories.filter((value) => value !== item)
      );
      setSelectedItems((prevItems) => [...prevItems, item]);
    }
  };

  const removeItem = (e, item) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setSelectedItems((items) => items.filter((value) => value !== item));
    setCategories((prevCategories) => [...prevCategories, item]);
  };

  return (
    <ClickOutside onClickOutside={() => setIsActive(false)}>
      <div className="custom-select" onClick={() => setIsActive(!isActive)}>
        <div className="multi-select">
          <title>{title}</title>
          <div className="multi-select-wrapper">
            {selectedItems.length > 0 &&
              selectedItems.map((item) => (
                <span onClick={(e) => removeItem(e, item)}>{item}</span>
              ))}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={`dropDown-wrapper ${isActive ? "active" : ""}`}>
          <ul>
            {categories.length > 0 &&
              categories.map((item) => (
                <li onClick={() => selectItem(item)}>{item}</li>
              ))}
            <li
              style={{
                display: `${categories.length === 0 ? "block" : "none"}`,
              }}
            >
              No Result
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ClickOutside>
  );
}

export default Select;
```

I hope this will help you who has same issue with me.